# SQL Server 2008 - insert trigger not firing

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, triggers

I have a VB.NET application that is creating some `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE` statements based on the users selections. I can tell that the SQL is being successfully executed on SQL Server 2008 (I see the table records adjusting appropriately), except one of my insert triggers is not firing.

SQL generated by the application code:

```
insert into [RECLASS_BALANCE_ADJSTMNT]( PRGRM_REC_ID, DEDUCTN_REC_ID, RBA_YR_PD_NUM, RBA_AMOUNT, RBA_TYPE, ADJUSTER_USER_ID ) 
values (5504, 8154, dbo.getCurrentYrPdNum(), abs(-21510.70), 'M', '10139638');

insert into [MATCH] (DEDUCTN_REC_ID, PRGRM_REC_ID, YR_PD_NUM, MATCH_TYPE_FLG)
values (8154, 5504, dbo.getCurrentYrPdNum(), 'M');

delete from [POTENTIAL_MATCH] 
where deductn_rec_id = 8154 
  and prgrm_rec_id = 5504;

update [PROGRAM_GL_DTL] 
set MATCH_FLG = 'Y', MATCH_FLG_MODIFIED_TIMESTAMP = getdate() 
where PRGRM_REC_ID = 5504;

update [DEDUCTION] 
set MATCH_FLG = MATCH_FLG + 1
where DEDUCTN_REC_ID = 8154;
```

`INSERT` trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[check_partial_offset_status] 
ON [dbo].[RECLASS_BALANCE_ADJSTMNT] 
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @deductnRecId int;
    DECLARE @deductnBalance decimal(18,2);
    DECLARE @deductnOriginalAmount decimal(18,2);

    SELECT @deductnRecId = i.deductn_rec_id FROM inserted i; 

    SELECT @deductnBalance = ds.ytd_amt, @deductnOriginalAmount = ds.original_invoice_amount 
    FROM deduction_summary_updt ds 
    WHERE ds.deductn_rec_id = @deductnRecId;

    IF ABS(@deductnBalance) > 0
    BEGIN
        UPDATE deduction 
        SET comment_id = 12 
        WHERE deductn_rec_id = @deductnRecId;
    END  --partial matched

    IF @deductnBalance = @deductnOriginalAmount
    BEGIN
        UPDATE deduction 
        SET comment_id = 6 
        WHERE deductn_rec_id = @deductnRecId;
    END   --unmatched

    IF @deductnBalance = 0
    BEGIN
        UPDATE deduction 
        SET comment_id = 9 
        WHERE deductn_rec_id = @deductnRecId; 
    END   --fully matched

    DECLARE @prgrmRecId int;
    DECLARE @prgrmBalance decimal(18,2);
    DECLARE @prgrmOriginalAmount decimal(18,2);

    SELECT @prgrmRecId = i.prgrm_rec_id FROM inserted i;

    SELECT @prgrmBalance = rs.ytd_amt, @prgrmOriginalAmount = rs.reclass_amount 
    FROM reclass_summary rs 
    WHERE rs.prgrm_rec_id = @prgrmRecId;

    IF ABS(@prgrmBalance) > 0
    BEGIN
        UPDATE program_gl_dtl 
        SET comment_id = 12 
        WHERE prgrm_rec_id = @prgrmRecId;
    END    --partial matched

    IF @prgrmBalance = @prgrmOriginalAmount
    BEGIN
        UPDATE program_gl_dtl 
        SET comment_id = 5 
        WHERE prgrm_rec_id = @prgrmRecId;
    END    --unmatched

    IF @prgrmBalance = 0
    BEGIN
        UPDATE program_gl_dtl 
        SET comment_id = 10 
        WHERE prgrm_rec_id = @prgrmRecId; 
    END    --fully matched      
END
GO
```

I'm trying to understand why the "INSERT INTO [RECLASS_BALANCE_ADJSTMNT].." generated by the application code does not cause the trigger to fire.

I appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Your trigger has a MAJOR flaw. It assumes there will only ever be a single row inserted. This is not how sql server works. It fires once per operation, not once per row. Your logic in your trigger needs to be set based which this isn't.

Comment: How do you *know* that the trigger didn't fire?

Comment: Yeah, how do you know it isn't firing? I often create a trigger log table with one field and first thing in a trigger, I insert into it some message to see what is happening. And do heed Sean Lange's warning.